# Box.com API: coadmin role

Tags: api, box-api

In Box.com for Enterprises, 3 additional sections of access-control options are shown when I enable **Co-Admin** role in the UI:

[image]

Is there a way to manage these coadmin "suboptions" through the API?

I've browsed Box.com API docs but I haven't found anything related to these, it only appears as 3 role options (admin, coadmin, user) for the user

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. Very good point...  Stay tuned.